# Fixed and variable Circle question

Tags: conic-sections

Two perpendicular normals to variable Circle are tangent to fixed circle $\ C_1$ with radius 2 and locus of centre of variable circle be the curve $\ C_2$, then find the product of maximum and minimum distance between the curves  $\ C_1$&  $\ C_2$.

My approach: Normal always pass through centre of circle . The normals are perpendicular to each other. B
ut not able to proceed

Comment: What are perpendicular normals to circle?

Comment: I mean line passing through centre and are mutually perpendicular

Comment: But then variable circle has fixed center

Comment: Normals are also tangent to $C_1$, and two perpendicular tangents form a square with respective radii. Hence...

Answer (score 2):

We denote the center of variable circle by $O$, whose loci is the curve $C_2$. The center of the fixed circle $C_1$ is at $A$. Two perpendicular tangents to $C_1$ are passing through $O$ and touch the circle at $P$ and $Q$.

[image: circle]

Since the circle's radius is perpendicular to the tangent line,
$$AP\perp OP\quad\text{&}\quad AQ\perp OQ$$
and since $OP\perp OQ$ and $AP=AQ$ then $APOQ$ is a square whose side length is $2$.

This would imply that the distance between $A$ and $O$ is always a constant ($=2\sqrt{2}$), and since the point $A$ is fixed, then $O$ lies on a circle around $A$. In other words, $C_2$ is a circle with radius $2\sqrt{2}$.

To find the maximum and minimum distance between two circles, simply pass a line between their centers which in this case is any diameter of $C_2$. Evidently, the least distance between two points on $C_1$ and $C_2$ is equal to $OX$ and the farthest ones are $X$ and $Y$. Therefore, the product of maximum and minimum distances are
$$OX\cdot XY=(2\sqrt{2}-2)(2\sqrt{2}+2)=4$$